# How to resize uploaded images in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, resize

I'm creating a website in which there's an administration page where the user can upload an image file. My question is if is it possible to resize the image after the upload and to change the quality of it, in such a way to have low weight images in the folder of the website.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See  here  :
http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/image-resizing-during-upload-in-asp-net-using-c/2/